# Should topic and queue names in JMS be separated by slashes or dots?

Tags: queue, jms, message-queue, jms-topic

Depending on where you look, examples and/or documentation for Topic and Queue names for JMS are often separated by a forward slash, or by a dot.

What is the correct/standard naming convention, or does it even matter?

E.g.: should my topic be named "masterdata.customer" or "masterdata/customer" ?

Why would you pick one convention over the other?

Thanks

Comment: I believe the AMQP specification requires "." as separator, so for compatibility that would be preferred, but otherwise, this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: AMQP 1.0 does not define a separator, nor does JMS etc.  Different broker implementations have different addressing semantics